# Expressing this in terms of the probability formula

Tags: probability

Say the probability that a man solves a problem =1/3. I.e P(solve)=1/3.

How would I express this in terms of probability = number of favorable outcomes/ total possible outcomes? Since the only two outcomes here are 'solved' and 'unsolved' and they are not equally probable.

Comment: Note that "number of favorable outcomes/ total possible outcomes" only works and makes sense if every single possible outcome is equally likely. If it's not, forget that fraction. Aside from that, you have discovered one of the grat philosophical questions about randomness and probability: What do the probabilities of different outcomes mean when an event only happens once? There is no definitive answer, and there are different schools of thought. The maths is the same, though, so I don't worry too much personally.

Comment: @arthur if it can't be written in terms of this formula, what does probability mean and how is it calculated? What are these different schools of thought and are they relevant at a high School level?

Comment: Most probabilities are estimated in practice. This is what a bookie does in estimating the odds (probabilities) of any  horse winning a race. The probability value in the first instance is based on experience, form, the ground etc. After that, this value can be adjusted to take account of betting patterns. Where bookies really make money is in using the laws of probability. Based on the probabilities set, they can work out probabilities of other events like which will come first, second or third. In practice then, probability is more about combining probabilities than setting their value.

Comment: @arthur and also, what does that mean for formulas like P(A Union B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A intersection B) which were derived using sets and the number of elements in them

Comment: That formula now becomes an axiom of probability. Based on experience and the special case of equally likely outcomes it is taken to be a general principle for the calculation of the probability of combined events. As Arthur said, it is a philosophical issue as to what sense it is objectively true.

Comment: @paul Hmm, interesting. Probability is more abstract than I thought

Comment: Since the question specifically refers to the frequentist definition of probability, then it seems clear that the interpretation for this situation is that there is a set of problems, that the person has the ability to solve 1/3 of them, and all problems are equally likely to be chosen to be attempted. The "outcomes" are whether or not a particular problem is solved.

Comment: Since the question specifically refers to the frequentist definition of probability, then it seems clear that the interpretation for this situation is that there is a set of men, that 1/3 of them can solve the problem, and all men are equally likely to do the problem. The "outcomes" are whether or not a particular person does the problem....